# Twitter Bootstrap to print a long column on one page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

Using Bootstrap v3.3.7 I have a page with two columns. When I print this page I want to print only one column but I'd like it to fit onto one A4 page.

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <!-- long list of input fields content goes here -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstname">First name</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" name="firstname" type="text" value="" id="firstname">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" name="lastname" type="text" value="" id="lastname">
    </div>
    <!-- about 20 more input fields go here -->
</div>

<div class="col-xs-8 hidden-print">
    <!-- Some content that will not get printed -->
</div>
```

I'm printing only the first column (second column will be hidden from print), but because it's quite long it spans onto two printed pages. I want to keep it on one page and since I have the right half of the page free I thought I can break the left column into two, so that it fits on one page.

Is that possible with just CSS or I'd have to change my HTML for print only?

Answer (score 0):

Boostrap is great!
I just found a solution. Use col-md-* for desktop screen and col-xs-* for small screen and print in my case.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
        <!-- long list of input fields content goes here -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname">First name</label>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="firstname" type="text" value="" id="firstname">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- this is where on desktop I still have one column but on print (small screen) I break into two 50% columns -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" name="lastname" type="text" value="" id="lastname">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-8 hidden-print">
    <!-- Some content that will not get printed -->
</div>
```